# Create new column from values after first underscore within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to create a new column that contains the values after the first underscore, and dropping these values and keeping the middle, if there are two underscores (essentially maintaining the middle value)

data

```
    col1        col2
    i_ba        1
    i_sapp      1
    h_sapp_ii   1
    h_sapp_led  1
    v_bu        2
    v_bu        2
```

desired

```
col1         col2       type
i_ba         1          ba
i_sapp       1          sapp
h_sapp_ii    1          sapp
h_sapp_led   1          sapp
v_bu         2          bu
v_bu         2          bu
```

doing

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\w*?_([^_]*)(?:_)?')
```

I am just not sure how to create a new column with these values. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Wait, is your question just how to assign the values to a column?  Then you just need to change the column assigned to in your last line.  I.e. `df['type'] = ...` instead of `df['col1'] = ...`; provided that your code is working, which it seems to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pandas string `split`, as well as pandas string indexing:

```
>>> df['type'] = df['col1'].str.split('_').str[1]
>>> df
         col1  col2  type
0        i_ba     1    ba
1      i_sapp     1  sapp
2   h_sapp_ii     1  sapp
3  h_sapp_led     1  sapp
4        v_bu     2    bu
5        v_bu     2    bu
```

[See here in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings).  Indexing with `[1]` means you access everything after the first underscore, up to the second.  If there is no underscore, `NaN` is returned for that row.